# Placeholder hides after deleting last component

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using Sitecore 8.1, When I delete the last component from the place holder using page editor, the place holder itself is getting vanished. I could not find why this is happening.

Comment: Is that placeholder located in that specific rendering that you are removing?
If you are removing the view where placeholder is added than then placeholder will get vanished.

Comment: Are you sure it is really gone, or just not visible anymore? Can you check in the html with some browser tools..

Comment: @NikkiPunjabi Thanks for the comment
I have created a master layout with one place holder('main')
and Added a rendering(say 'OneColumn') with one place holder ('col1') and some other text
And if I delete the 'OneColumn' rendering then no longer I can see the placeholder 'main' but still I can see the text from 'OneColumn'.

Comment: @Gatogordo Hi,
It is not really gone I checked the html but not visible, I can see the html, I could not understand what I did wrong

Comment: Could be a css issue.. can you compare the styling after deleting with an empty placeholder (before adding anything)?

Comment: Do you have placeholder settings item for the `main` placeholder?

Comment: Standard issue with Sitecore, I've seen this happen as well. If you save the page the placeholder will be visible again, or you the "Insert Rendering" button in the top left corner of the page.

Comment: @MarekMusielak Yes Marek I have.

Comment: @jammykam Its  working if I save the changes, still could not find the issue, Is it confirmed that is an expected issue? Any alternative ways to fix this?

Comment: @Jojo No idea, I've noticed the issue but not looked into resolving it. I would raise it with Sitecore Support.

Comment: Did you report this to sitecore? Can you confirm that this is a sitecore bug? We have the same issue in Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Just ran into this on Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160302